# How multiply month by the number of days

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

I need to multiply each month of my data by the number of days in the corresponding month. The data are average monthly precipitation and multiplying by the number of days will have accumulated precipitation. I would like a pythonic way of doing this (maybe xarray or pandas). My code at below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6

import xarray as xr

ncfile = 'https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/dodsC/' \
         'Datasets/cmap/std/precip.mon.mean.nc'

with xr.open_dataset(ncfile, autoclose=True) as dset:
    lat = dset['lat']
    lon = dset['lon']
    precip = dset['precip']

print(precip)
```

For Example:

The first three months from data are: 1979-01-01, 1979-02-01, 1979-03-01, so:

```
print(precip[0:3, 10, 10].values)
[ 0.81   0.76999998  0.70999998]

0.81 * 31
0.76999998 * 28
0.70999998 * 31
```

Comment: unable to read the data, maybe if you can show the DF in pandas that you're able to obtain, and expected output.

Comment: Can you add a portion of the data to this question.  Maybe a couple of records for three months?

Comment: This seems to be a working URL for the dataset https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/fileServer/Datasets/cmap/std/precip.mon.mean.nc

Comment: Data not loading. 400 bad request message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `daysinmonth` (or alias `days_in_month`) property:

```
precip_month = precip * precip.time.dt.daysinmonth
```